# How can I log power consumption on the UP board?

Tags: logging, upboard

In the project related to image detection, I use UP-Board with the Intel CPU. There is also mounted camera via USB and Coral's USB Edge TPU for accelerate inferences of ML model.

In some situations, the board turns off. It seems to me that this is due to too high power consumption.

So my question is whether there is a possibility to monitor the power consumption so as to catch the power consumption at which activities are too high. Is it possible to use some kind of logger?

Comment: What kind of a camera are you using? and are you sure the upboard is available to get the current which it needed? Your supplier specs also needed to know.

Comment: **UP Squared specifications:**
OS: Ubuntu
CPU: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU N4200 @ 1.10GHz
Power: 5V DC-in @ 4A-6A (config for set at 6A)
Camera: Basler acA1440-73gc

I’m using 2xUSB 3.0. One for the camera and the second one for TPU. 

Answering to your question, I'm not sure if the board gets the current which it needs. I've tried to measure that using PowerTop, but it's insufficient. And now I'm looking for some kind of solution that gives me information about what causes the board to shut down in some circumstances.

Comment: Is your power supply a battery or it takes power from a wall plug? And your camera works with pylonviewer application well? I also used basler with an upboard but my camera not ace. Try your camera with basler company application first. And what are those situationns which you mentioned? *"In some situations, the board turns off."* Maybe its not about the camera but the code.

Comment: It always takes power from a wall and it works fine with pylonviewer. I've never had any problems with that. 

The device turns off during operation (ML script is running). I'm using it for the real-time tracing objects program. 

The strange thing is that only 2 devices are affected, on the other 4, I haven't noticed any problem. That's why I would like to know how to test power consumption. Can the situation be related to a momentary too high voltage?

Comment: I vote on the problem should be on the code but any code shouldnt let the board shutdown. You may change the boards and cameras with each other so you may see always same upboards shutdown then we understand, the problem is totally on boards. I think you can open a post [here](https://forum.up-community.org/) too which helps you more.